# Winlogon Init delay

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am trying to trace the boot time of a Windows 7 Professional machine and found the following times:

```
Phase #, Phase Name, Start Time (s), End Time (s), Duration (s)
1, Pre Session Init, 0.000000000, 6.218684586, 6.218684586
2, Session Init, 6.218684586, 19.716180585, 13.497495999
3, Winlogon Init, 19.716180585, 164.393575644, 144.677395059
4, Explorer Init, 34.856013361, 39.280802294, 4.424788933
5, Post Boot, 39.280802294, 85.280802294, 46.000000000
```

The winlogon init seems to take a long time. What can be a reason?

[image]

Comment: Is this a standalone machine, or on a domain? What else is installed on it?

Comment: yeah, this is a standalone machine

Comment: Are you noticing any event log entries for winlogon?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Mark Russinovich's blog, specifically [The Case of the Slow Logons](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx)
.  The guy is a demi-God, and this particular article is very good.

BTW, what tool are you using to capture/present your data - looks very good?

Comment: [Windows Performance Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx), specifically, `xbootmgr` and `xperf` it looks like.